# python pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to open a window in pygame but keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

This is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.list_modes()
pygame.display.set_mode([700, 500])
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
```

If I do not have 'pygame.display.list_modes()' included it has the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
pygame.error: No available video device
```

I have used 'pygame.init()' so do not know what has gone wrong, Can anyone please help me to figure out what has gone wrong? Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help my out.

I don't think it makes a difference but I am using Repl.it to code this.

Comment: Try to run the program on your computer. It should actually work, so it could be a problem with repl.it.

Comment: Thanks it works now = ) @skrx

Comment: On repl.it or your computer?

Comment: BTW: `repl.it` may runs code on server without monitor and video card so it may have problem with video device. Besides PyGame can't run on server computer and display on client computer.